# how to check connect internet after click button

Tags: ios

I have 1 button in Login page and I want to check  user connected internet or not after user click button if user not connected internet I want to show alertView.

Pleas help me to coding, Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1083701/1548523

Comment: how to add Tony Million's version of Reachability.h and Reachability.m to the project?

Answer (score 0):

Check Apple's sample code [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) then you will know how to use it.

Comment: I don't know how to use Reachability.

Comment: @user2738453 You are so lazy, he has given you the link to sample code which shows how to use it! Would you atleast look at it?